# How to display hierarchical data with slicer Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, hierarchy

I have a data table:

[image]

I need to perform KPI for Organization, Team and every employee, KPI of Team is the data of the employees in the team, KPI of Organization is the data of all employees. The result I want is a diagram showing 3 KPIs of the selected object.

[image]

To do this, I created a Hierachy Slicer to filter the objects that need to be calculated:

[image]

My slicer works fine if I create Measure to calculate each KPI value but it doesn't work when I create a new Data table to store KPI values, I don't know where the problem is, please help me.